# if $e$ is an idempotent, then $Re$ is a projective module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, idempotents

I would like to show that if $R$ is a ring with $1$, and $e$ is an idempotent in $R$, then $Re$ is a projective module.

My idea is to show that $R = Re \oplus R(1-e)$. It's clear to me that $R = Re + R(1-e)$, but I am having trouble showing that $Re \cap R(1-e) = \{0\}$. I tried that if $x \in Re \cap R(1-e)$, then $x = re = r'(1-e)$ for some $r,r' \in R$. Then $re = re^2 = r'(1-e)e = r'(e - e^2) = 0$, but how can I show $r$ is $0$ if $R$ need not necessarily be a domain?

Comment: You weren't trying to prove that $r=0$. You were proving that $x=0$, which you already did since $re=x$.

Comment: Oh my, my brain seems to be off tonight. Thank you!

Comment: On the intersection the right action by $e$ and $1-e$ are given by the identity, but the product of both is zero. So you can choose $r=r'=x$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, your approach is very good. Here is another, which you might like.

There is an obvious surjective $R$-module homomorphism $\varphi \colon R \to Re$ given by $r \mapsto re$, so we obtain an exact sequence of $R$-modules

$$0 \to \ker(\varphi) \to R \xrightarrow{\varphi} Re \to 0$$

To show that $Re$ is a direct summand of $R$, it suffices to show that this sequence is split. The inclusion $i \colon Re \to R$ is a splitting, since $\varphi(i(re)) = re\cdot e = re^{2} = re$, so $R \cong \ker(\varphi) \oplus Re$.